# Incompatible type for trait when implementing the trait using generics

Tags: rust

Compiling the following code:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

pub enum StorageType {
    // ...
}

pub trait Storable {
    fn get_nblocks(&self) -> usize;
    fn get_storage(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<Storage>>;
}

pub trait Storage {
    fn store(&mut self, data: &Storable);
    fn get_type(&self) -> &StorageType;
}

pub struct DataVolume<T: Storage> {
    nblocks: usize,
    storage: Rc<RefCell<T>>,
}
impl<T: Storage> DataVolume<T> {
    pub fn new(nblocks: usize, storage: Rc<RefCell<T>>) -> DataVolume<T> {
        let this = DataVolume { nblocks: nblocks, storage: storage.clone() };
        storage.borrow_mut().store(&this);
        this
    }
}
impl<T: Storage> Storable for DataVolume<T> {
    fn get_nblocks(&self) -> usize {
        self.nblocks
    }
    fn get_storage(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<T>> {
        self.storage.clone()
    }
}
```

gives me:

```
src/store.rs:37:5: 39:6 error: method `get_storage` has an incompatible type
 for trait: expected trait store::Storage, found type parameter [E0053]
src/store.rs:37     fn get_storage(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<T>> {
src/store.rs:38         self.storage.clone()
src/store.rs:39     }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I tried many things, and this is what I thought would finally be correct...
Is my design of data structures itself wrong in the Rust world?

Comment: Well, keep in mind that in Rust, you must know the size of what you're returning during compile time. What exactly is size of `<T:Storage>` during compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trait definition says:

```
fn get_storage(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<Storage>>
```

but your implementation is

```
fn get_storage(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<T>>
```

As the compiler is telling you - these are not compatible. The trait definition says that you will be returning an *unsized type* (which may or may not be possible, depending). The implementation says you are returning a *specific* type, but one that will be determined at compile time.

Let's pick the generic solution, as the compiler will *monomorphize* (generate specialized code for) each type you use. This can be faster but involve code bloat. Change your trait to:

```
pub trait Storable<T>
    where T: Storage
{
    fn get_nblocks(&self) -> usize;
    fn get_storage(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<T>>;
}
```

The whole program will then look like ([playpen](http://is.gd/usVurY)):

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

pub enum StorageType {
    // ...
}

pub trait Storable<T>
    where T: Storage
{
    fn get_nblocks(&self) -> usize;
    fn get_storage(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<T>>;
}

pub trait Storage {
    fn store(&mut self, data: &Storable<Self>);
    fn get_type(&self) -> &StorageType;
}

pub struct DataVolume<T>
    where T: Storage
{
    nblocks: usize,
    storage: Rc<RefCell<T>>,
}

impl<T> DataVolume<T>
    where T: Storage
{
    pub fn new(nblocks: usize, storage: Rc<RefCell<T>>) -> DataVolume<T> {
        let this = DataVolume { nblocks: nblocks, storage: storage.clone() };
        storage.borrow_mut().store(&this);
        this
    }
}

impl<T> Storable<T> for DataVolume<T>
    where T: Storage
{
    fn get_nblocks(&self) -> usize {
        self.nblocks
    }
    fn get_storage(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<T>> {
        self.storage.clone()
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm wondering what the difference between `pub struct DataVolume<T: Storage> {...}` vs `pub struct DataVolume<T> where T: Storage {...}` is... Is the first usage deprecated version of the second?

Comment: @JohnFrancis they are *basically* the same, but `where` did come second. I prefer the `where` form because it gets all ugly and twisted trying to cram it all in `<>`. The only difference I know of is that the first form allows usage of `?Sized`.